# how to capture content from a series of views in ZF

Tags: zend-framework

I have an website with lots of modules/controllers/actions. I am trying to use existing content for an offline PDF report.

To simplify the problem, I want to capture the content of 2 actions:

```
$content = [
     'first'  => 'module_1/controller_1/action_1',
     'second' => 'module_2/controller_2/action_2'
];
```

All these actions exist and generate the content independently.
I am adding the requests to the actionStack, but I am not sure on how to execute them and gather the final content.

```
 $stack  = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('actionStack');
 foreach ($content as $key => $path){
      list($module, $controller, $action) = explode("/", $path);
      $stack->actionToStack($action, $controller, $module)
 }
```

But this does not work as I am expecting and I get no response. 
What would be the correct way to capture the rendered content of those actions?

Comment: where do you capture? in controller or in view?

Comment: @MaxP. neither, I capture in another part of the application, which is called from another controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views helper `Zend_View_Helper_Action` can capture the result of some controller work

```
function f($action, $controller, $module, array $params = array())
{
    $view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    return $view->view->getHelper('action')->action($action, $controller, $module, $params);
}

$content = [
     'first'  => 'module_1/controller_1/action_1',
     'second' => 'module_2/controller_2/action_2'
];

foreach ($content as $key => $path){
      list($module, $controller, $action) = explode("/", $path);
      $content = f($action, $controller, $module)
}
```

Or try to write custom function based on `Zend_View_Helper_Action` code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this works and returns all the html from the view, but no CSS or JS seems to be executed. I mean resources that exist in the view with $this->headScript()  and $this->headStyle(). Is there a way of injecting/running those as well?

Comment: Do you mean layout with common part for all templates?

Comment: yes. I think so. I would like to get the result including the layout.

Comment: plugin `Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout::postDispatch` processes layout, but I don't know the details